# How to migrate ejabberd database from SQL backend to Mnesia?

Tags: mysql, ejabberd

There is pretty supported action to move from Mnesia to SQL, a special command `ejabberdctl export2sql` (in older versions it used to be called `export2odbc`). Some setups may need that because Mnesia is limited to 2GiB and blah blah blah.

In my case there is really no need to have an external database. There are around 10-15 active users and no more than 30 of total users, and the size of the export from SQL database is around 200 kB.

Somebody in the past did that thing, exported a database into SQL (specifically, MySQL). How can I revert that change?

Can `export_piefxis` help me somehow? What it does?

---

**Update 1**. After some exploration I found that only two modules have some data in the SQL database: `mod_roster` and `mod_vcard`. So only those need to be converted. Is there a way to convert their data externally and load into ejabberd? I mean, there is a `ejabberdctl dump_table`, but again no reverse command.

Also, `export_piefxis` doesn't seem to help. It just exports zero content, while there is data in the database and it is fetched when I connect with e.g. newly instantiated client.

**Update 2**. Software: Debian 11.2 LXC container running on Proxmox VE 6.4-1 host. Ejabberd 21.01-2 installed with `apt` from standard Debian repo.

The database was migrated from old Ejabberd of around version 2.1, that was running on Gentoo and last updated in 2015. I don't have that machine at my discretion anymore. Mnesia database migration was done as follows:

```sh
# on the old machine
ejabberdctl backup /tmp/ejabberd@localhost.mnesia 
ejabberdctl mnesia_change_nodename ejabberd@localhost ejabberd@jabber2 \
           /tmp/ejabberd@localhost.mnesia /tmp/ejabberd@jabber2.mnesia
# on the new machine (starting with empty database)
ejabberdctl install_fallback /tmp/ejabberd@jabber2.mnesia
ejabberdctl stop
ejabberdctl start
```

The configuration on the new machine just references the same MySQL database for `mod_roster` and `mod_vcard`.

`ejabberd.yml`:

```yaml
loglevel: info

log_rotate_count: 0

hosts:
  - "example.org"

host_config:
  "rterm.ru":
    sql_type: mysql
    sql_server: "dbserver"
    sql_database: "ejabberd"
    sql_username: "ejabberd"
    sql_password: "password"
    auth_method: [external]

certfiles:
  - "/etc/ejabberd/ejabberd.pem"

acme:
  auto: false

define_macro:
  'TLS_CIPHERS': "HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!3DES:@STRENGTH"
  'TLS_OPTIONS':
    - "no_sslv3"
    - "no_tlsv1"
    - "no_tlsv1_1"
    - "cipher_server_preference"
    - "no_compression"


c2s_ciphers: 'TLS_CIPHERS'
s2s_ciphers: 'TLS_CIPHERS'
c2s_protocol_options: 'TLS_OPTIONS'
s2s_protocol_options: 'TLS_OPTIONS'

listen:
  -
    port: 5222
    ip: "::"
    module: ejabberd_c2s
    max_stanza_size: 262144
    shaper: c2s_shaper
    access: c2s
    starttls_required: true
    protocol_options: 'TLS_OPTIONS'
  -
    port: 5223
    ip: "::"
    module: ejabberd_c2s
    max_stanza_size: 262144
    shaper: c2s_shaper
    access: c2s
    tls: true
    protocol_options: 'TLS_OPTIONS'
  -
    port: 5269
    ip: "::"
    module: ejabberd_s2s_in
    max_stanza_size: 524288
  -
    port: 5443
    ip: "::"
    module: ejabberd_http
    tls: true
    protocol_options: 'TLS_OPTIONS'
    request_handlers:
      /admin: ejabberd_web_admin
      /api: mod_http_api
      /bosh: mod_bosh
      /upload: mod_http_upload
      /ws: ejabberd_http_ws
  -
    port: 5280
    ip: "::"
    module: ejabberd_http
    tls: false
    request_handlers:
# This runs behind reverse HTTP proxy with Let's Encrypt, which is neighbour container on the same host, so this is safe
      /admin: ejabberd_web_admin
      /bosh: mod_bosh
      /upload: mod_http_upload
  -
    port: 1883
    ip: "::"
    module: mod_mqtt
    backlog: 1000

auth_method: [external]
extauth_program: "/etc/ejabberd/auth_mysql.py"
extauth_pool_size: 5

disable_sasl_mechanisms:
  - "X-OAUTH2"

s2s_use_starttls: required

acl:
  admin:
    user:
       - "admin@example.org"

  local:
    user_regexp: ""
  loopback:
    ip:
      - 127.0.0.0/8
      - ::1/128

access_rules:
  local:
    allow: local
  c2s:
    deny: blocked
    allow: all
  announce:
    allow: admin
  configure:
    allow: admin
  muc_create:
    allow: local
  pubsub_createnode:
    allow: local
  trusted_network:
    allow: loopback

api_permissions:
  "console commands":
    from:
      - ejabberd_ctl
    who: all
    what: "*"
  "admin access":
    who:
      access:
        allow:
          - acl: loopback
          - acl: admin
      oauth:
        scope: "ejabberd:admin"
        access:
          allow:
            - acl: loopback
            - acl: admin
    what:
      - "*"
      - "!stop"
      - "!start"
  "public commands":
    who:
      ip: 127.0.0.1/8
    what:
      - status
      - connected_users_number

shaper:
  normal:
    rate: 3000
    burst_size: 20000
  fast: 200000

shaper_rules:
  max_user_sessions: 10
  max_user_offline_messages:
    5000: admin
    100: all
  c2s_shaper:
    none: admin
    normal: all
  s2s_shaper: fast

modules:
  mod_adhoc: {}
  mod_admin_extra: {}
  mod_announce:
    access: announce
  mod_avatar: {}
  mod_blocking: {}
  mod_bosh: {}
  mod_caps: {}
  mod_carboncopy: {}
  mod_client_state: {}
  mod_configure: {}
  mod_disco: {}
  mod_fail2ban: {}
  mod_http_api: {}
  mod_http_upload:
    put_url: https://@HOST@:5443/upload
    custom_headers:
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "https://@HOST@"
      "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET,HEAD,PUT,OPTIONS"
      "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type"
  mod_last: {}
  mod_mqtt: {}
  mod_muc:
    access:
      - allow
    access_admin:
      - allow: admin
    access_create: muc_create
    access_persistent: muc_create
    access_mam:
      - allow
    default_room_options:
      mam: true
  mod_muc_admin: {}
  mod_offline:
    access_max_user_messages: max_user_offline_messages
  mod_ping: {}
  mod_pres_counter:
    count: 5
    interval: 60
  mod_privacy: {}
  mod_private: {}
  mod_proxy65:
    access: local
    max_connections: 5
  mod_pubsub:
    access_createnode: pubsub_createnode
    plugins:
      - flat
      - pep
    force_node_config:
      "eu.siacs.conversations.axolotl.*":
        access_model: open
      storage:bookmarks:
        access_model: whitelist
  mod_push: {}
  mod_push_keepalive: {}
  mod_roster:
    db_type: sql # This is what I want to get rid of
    versioning: true
  mod_s2s_dialback: {}
  mod_shared_roster: {}
  mod_sic: {}
  mod_stream_mgmt:
    resend_on_timeout: if_offline
  mod_stun_disco: {}
  mod_vcard:
    db_type: sql # And this
    search: false
  mod_vcard_xupdate: {}
  mod_version: {}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, there's a feature incompatibility: you are asking ejabberd the details about the registered accounts, but ejabberd doesn't know what accounts exist.

You have ejabberd configured to use [extauth](https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/configuration/authentication/#external-script), which means ejabberd uses that script to [check if an account exists](https://docs.ejabberd.im/developer/guide/#external) or not... But that script never reports the list of registered accounts.

This is a problem when you want to know the list of registered accounts:

- export existing accounts using export_piefxis
- view list of accounts in ejabberd WebAdmin

This was reported in
https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/issues/3705

One solution would be to enable the option [auth_use_cache](https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/configuration/toplevel/#auth-use-cache) so that each login attempt gives a hint that ejabberd stores. Wait a few days or weeks, and later when you request the list of "registered accounts", ejabberd reads that auth cache and uses it.

The problem is that you would need to wait for all the registered accounts to login and leave that cached information in ejabberd...

The good news: there's a way you can fill the auth cache with the accounts:

1. Get the list of registered accounts yourself, manually, in some way
2. Enable [auth_use_cache](https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/configuration/toplevel/#auth-use-cache) in ejabberd and restart
3. Run this command for every account you want to export. This will ensure extauth is run for that account, and the auth cache stores this hint:

   ejabberdctl check_account user123 localhost
4. Just for curiosity, you can view the list of registered accounts (in fact it's only the list of auth cached accounts...)

   ejabberdctl registered_users localhost
   admin
   user123
5. Now you can finally run export_piefxis
6. Remember: that auth cache information is deleted when ejabberd stops.
7. Once it's exported, you can revert configuration

Comment: That's reasonable explanation. Thanks for suggestions on how to proceed, I'll give it a try!

Answer (score 0):

> Can export_piefxis help me somehow? What it does?

Yes, that should be the command that does what you want: run it when SQL storage is still in use. Once you have the contents in XML files, configure ejabberd to use Mnesia and import those files.

> Also, export_piefxis doesn't seem to help.

It crashed? Or it simply exported zero contents?

Comment: I retried. It exported zero contents (two files, one 180 bytes and other is 132 — latter is my host data). While, connecting to jabber with the new client I can see roster and vcard data fetched from the sql database,

Comment: I installed ejabberd from git, configured to use MySQL for auth and default storage, registered an account, added a contact and edited vcard. Then exported, and the second xml contains the user details: ...<host ...<user name='admin' password='asd'><vCard xmlns='vcard-temp'><N><GIVEN>...

Comment: Update your original question detailing what ejabberd version is running, how it was installed, its configuration file (comment private details)

Comment: I added all the details you wanted